# Xcode 6 GM - Unable to use playgounds

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

I've recently deleted Xcode 5 and installed Xcode 6 GM on my Mac.  I've started a new iOS project in Swift and have run a number of XCT unit tests successfully.

To resolve a simple coding problem (involving the use of the floor function) I created a playground file in the application.  Unfortunately, it crashes each time I use it, with the following message "Playground execution terminated because the playground process exited unexpectedly.".

Restarting Xcode does not resolve the problem.  In addition, after restarting Xcode forgets anything that was listed in the "Open Recent..." menu even if it was there before the restart.

I'm guessing that there are some basic Xcode settings that are screwed up.  Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Also, any idea as to why the first response to the question was to anonymously down-vote it would be appreciated, too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and got these messages in the console app.

> Blockquote Xcode[2092]: [MT] IDEPlaygroundEditor: Error encountered attempting to run playground: Error Domain=IDEPlaygroundErrorDomain Code=1 "An error occurred while trying to communicate with a helper application. You may need to restart Xcode before playgrounds will run again." UserInfo=0x7fd580130350 {NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while trying to communicate with a helper application. You may need to restart Xcode before playgrounds will run again.}

Restarting Xcode didn't help, but restarting my mac solved the problem.

Comment: I had forgotten that I had even asked this question!  In recent months, I ran into the same problem with Xcode 7 betas.  It turns out that the cause was Dropbox.  I was using Dropbox to synchronise my work across a couple of machines.  It appears that, in some versions of Xcode - particularly some beta versions, working with playgrounds that have been saved to a directory monitored by Dropbox really screws things up.  These days I usually turn Dropbox off when working with Xcode and turn in on and re-sync when I am finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try, Change the **Platform to "OS X"** from inspector on the right. and comments the **//import UIKit**.
unknown problems related to simulator settings for playground in Xcode 7 beta.

Answer (score -2):

Your error message:

```
Playground execution terminated because the playground process exited unexpectedly.
```

occurs usually because of faulty code. You should probably post it if you want further help.

As for your second issue:

- Open the **System Preferences** app.
- Navigate to **General** (usually first in the topmost section).
- Look down, there should be a setting called **Recent Items**.
- Change it from **None** to **15** (the default value, if I remember correctly).

And that's it.

---

Based upon your comment, I'd suggest changing `import UIKit var x = 1` to `import UIKit; var x = 1`.

Comment: In this case, it's not being caused by the code:

import UIKit

var x = 1

I'm not sure the code could be any simpler.  It also happens with the default playground code (which sets a simple String) before I enter any code of my own.

As to the second issue.  The recent items value is already set to 50 and the issue wasn't present in the previous Xcode installation.  So, not that either.  (And I've installed Xcode 6 twice so far.)

(It also appears Stack Exchange is ignoring my text formatting.)

Comment: Unfortunately, not that either.  The two statements were on different lines.  They just appeared on one line when entered into Stackoverflow.

In any case, I wouldn't expect such a trivial error to crash an Xcode playground.